# Xamarin Forms, UWP and ADAL authentication with WIA issue

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, uwp, adal, adfs3.0

I have been trying to get a Xamarin UWP app to authenticate with our federated Active Directory using the ADAL library.  I have used the source [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-windows-store) and followed the instructions, including enabling the Enterprise authentication settings, that should allow it to authenticate against our Azure ADFS.

When I run it in the Windows Phone 10 emulator it shows the Microsoft login page and when I enter a user id it pops up the usual AD authentication dialog.  When I enter my details into this however, it hangs.  This is the code in the example:

```
result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(todoListResourceId, 
           clientId, redirectURI, 
           new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto, true));
```

which seems to be the standard way of doing things.  I've stepped through the ADAL library and it's hanging in the second call to the WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync:

```
    public async Task<AuthorizationResult> AcquireAuthorizationAsync(Uri authorizationUri, Uri redirectUri, CallState callState)
    {
        bool ssoMode = ReferenceEquals(redirectUri, Constant.SsoPlaceHolderUri);
        if (this.promptBehavior == PromptBehavior.Never && !ssoMode && redirectUri.Scheme != Constant.MsAppScheme)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(AdalErrorMessageEx.RedirectUriUnsupportedWithPromptBehaviorNever, "redirectUri");
        }

        WebAuthenticationResult webAuthenticationResult;

        WebAuthenticationOptions options = (this.useCorporateNetwork &&
                                            (ssoMode || redirectUri.Scheme == Constant.MsAppScheme))
            ? WebAuthenticationOptions.UseCorporateNetwork
            : WebAuthenticationOptions.None;

        if (this.promptBehavior == PromptBehavior.Never)
        {
            options |= WebAuthenticationOptions.SilentMode;
        }

        try
        {
            if (ssoMode)
            {
                webAuthenticationResult =
                    await
                        WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(options, authorizationUri)
                            .AsTask()
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            else
            {
                webAuthenticationResult =
                    await
                        WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(options, authorizationUri, redirectUri)
                            .AsTask()
                            .ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
```

The emulator traffic isn't picked up by Fiddler and there is nothing in the logs on the ADFS farm so I'm at a bit of a loss as to what's going on.  Has anyone managed to get this to work and if so how did you do it?

Comment: Are you calling acquireToken().Result by any chance? If yes, then  you should be using async/await all the way

Comment: No I'm using the code as is from the sample.  That uses await rather than Result.  I've subsequently found that the app works on an actual Windows 10 mobile so there's something wrong with the way the emulator handles this.  The emulator has access to the internet so it's not a connection issue, but without Fiddler it's hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Does the WAB close once you authenticate?

Comment: I imagine it does on the mobile given that it gets past the authentication screen but I didn't do much debugging on that.  The mobile emulator just hangs.  I've left it running overnight but it just sits there doing nothing.